# Should we combine HSA and health-spending-account tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we combine the [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) and [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account) tags? Also, shouldn't it be [health-savings-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-savings-account) instead of [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account)?

Answer (score 2):

The one [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) tag works, in my opinion, although unlike the US-specific Roth IRA or 401(k), it would require a country tag if the question didn't provide context.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to have both the [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) and [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account) tags.  I'm used to HSA standing for "health savings account," but if it means "health spending account" in Canada (as is mentioned in [a comment](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/should-we-combine-hsa-and-health-spending-account-tags#comment405_327)), let's just use the [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) tag (which could stand for either), and make [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account) a synonym.  You could also make [health-savings-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-savings-account) a synonym for [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa), but that tag doesn't exist yet.

---

Edit: 3/3/2016

This is still bugging me.  It looks like everyone on this question agrees that there should only be one tag and [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) should be it, and yet we still have two, due to the low attention that this question has gotten.  Let's keep [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) and set up the other [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account) tag as a synonym.  If you agree, vote up JoeTaxpayer's answer (and mine) and vote down Alex B's answer (it looks like he disagrees with his own answer in the comments) and let's make this happen.

Comment: Your answer already has my vote.

Comment: I think we should go ahead and do this soon - I've marked the question with the `featured` tag so it'll hopefully get a bit more attention first.

Comment: Now implemented - I also made `health-savings-account` as another synonym to make it clear that `hsa` is intended to cover both. I've tweaked the tag wiki a bit too but it could do with more editing.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Thanks. And we did it before the 5-year mark. Not bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in favor of creating a synonym from [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa) -> [health-savings-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-savings-account) and from [health-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-spending-account) -> [health-savings-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-savings-account).

Comment: FWIW, "health spending account" appears to be the nomenclature here in Canada, whereas "health savings account" is more common in the U.S.

Comment: Heh, so maybe both long forms should go to hsa which is sufficiently ambiguous to cover both cases :)

Comment: @bstpierre I like your creative solution

Comment: @Chriswrea wikipedia agrees with you... Do we keep both long forms? Do we add a synonym to one of them?    If you have ideas, post another answer.