# Make fsa and flexible-spending-account synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Similar to the request [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/should-we-combine-hsa-and-health-spending-account-tags) to merge [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa)-related tags, Should we do the same for [fsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fsa) and [flexible-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible-spending-account)?

I stumbled across an FSA question and realized it didn't even have a tag wiki, added that (taking guidance from the HSA tag wiki), then discovered the extra tag - some questions have both, some are tagged with only one or the other, but they're all the same thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this seems to have support and no opposition, I've merged the two tags and made [flexible-spending-account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible-spending-account) a synonym for [fsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fsa). I did it that way round to be consistent with [hsa](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hsa), but I don't feel strongly and will could reverse it if there's a consensus for that.