# How should the tags for HRA be handled?

Tags: discussion, tags

The term HRA means two different things:

- In the U.S., HRA is Health Reimbursement Arrangement, an employer-funded benefit for medical expenses.
- In India, HRA is House Rent Allowance, a component of an employee's salary to be used for housing.

A couple of days ago, I created the [hra](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hra) tag for [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/87915/10997).  After doing that, I remembered that HRA meant something different in India, so I created the [health-reimbursement-arrangement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-reimbursement-arrangement) and [house-rent-allowance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rent-allowance) tags, and tagged a few questions with them.

After I did this, I had a couple of concerns:

- [health-reimbursement-arrangement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-reimbursement-arrangement) is a really long tagname.  Is that a problem?
- When you go to the [tag search box](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags) and type "hra", neither of the new tags comes up.  I was hoping that by putting the text "HRA" in the tag excerpt for both tags they would come up in a search, but no such luck.

Each of these topics has [several questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=hra) and deserves a tag, in my opinion.  So, my question is: What should we do for tags for these two topics?  Some options are:

1. Keep the tags as I have them now, [health-reimbursement-arrangement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-reimbursement-arrangement) and [house-rent-allowance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rent-allowance).  Don't worry about the long tagnames or the tag search problems.
2. Add "hra" to each tag name, so they become [hra-health-reimbursement-arrangement](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hra-health-reimbursement-arrangement) and [hra-house-rent-allowance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hra-house-rent-allowance). This would fix the search problem, but would make the tag names even longer.
3. Use one tag for both, [hra](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hra).  This is [what we decided to do with the HSA tag](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/10997), because there is an HSA in both the U.S. and Canada. However, both the American and Canadian HSA's are related to health expenses, and we have yet to get a question about Canadian HSAs.  The American and Indian HRAs really are completely unrelated.
4. Something else?

Comment: Great question. Looks like we are dealing with this thing for the first time. We should not just solve it once, but also come out with some guidelines for future similar conflicts. Given the number of questions; a tag is definitely required.

Answer (score 2):

> Add "hra" to each tag name,

I would prefer to go with adding hra to each tag. This should solve the problem. Native users in India/US would start typing hra and it would show both for them to select correct one. Some users would start by typing health or house and relevant tags would show up.

Comment: +1, I think this might be the best option. I'll wait a few more days before acting to see if we get any more feedback.